# Не пойму какой ответ Json нужен

Tags: c#, json, парсер

Скинули код и попросили помочь. Какой ответ должен парсить этот код Newtonsoft Json? Помогите, пожалуйста

```
public static void SetExchangePrices(JToken prices)
{
    priceLikesSell = Convert.ToDouble(prices[(object)"sell"][(object)"likes"].ToString());
    priceFollowersSell = Convert.ToDouble(prices[(object)"sell"][(object)"followers"].ToString());
    priceRepostSell = Convert.ToDouble(prices[(object)"sell"][(object)"repost"].ToString());
    priceLikesBuy = Convert.ToDouble(prices[(object)"buy"][(object)"likes"].ToString());
    priceFollowersBuy = Convert.ToDouble(prices[(object)"buy"][(object)"followers"].ToString());
    priceRepostBuy = Convert.ToDouble(prices[(object)"buy"][(object)"repost"].ToString());
}
```

Такой ответ не подходит:

```
{
  "prices": [
    {
      "sell": {
        "likes": "12345",
        "followers": "12345",
        "repost": "12345"
      },
      "buy": {
        "likes": "12345",
        "followers": "12345",
        "repost": "12345"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Какой должен выдавать ответ сервер для парсинга с помощью кода выше, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: почему вы решили, что `prices` - массив? Это скорее словарь

Comment: _попросили помочь_ - напишите ответ: "Не могу помочь. Не знаю".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если без изменения кода, то взгляните внимательней на строку:

```
prices[(object)"sell"][(object)"likes"]
```

У вас есть некий корневой `JToken` объект `prices` в котором вы берете `sell`, из которого берете `likes`.
Если у вас только этот код и вы дальше нечего не будете писать, то здесь вы не указываете на массив `prices` из JSON, а значит он у вас лишний и верным будет следующий вариант:

```
{
  "sell": {
    "likes": "12345",
    "followers": "12345",
    "repost": "12345"
  },
  "buy": {
    "likes": "12345",
    "followers": "12345",
    "repost": "12345"
  }
}
```

Но я очень советую вашему "другу" привести все в порядок, создать правильную структуру классов и работать с ней!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!